# route defined in flask returns 404

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, wsgi

I have a simple Flask script that has different routes defined with @app.route. The app is running through gunicorn on a nginx server.

The problem occurs when trying to access any route. Except for base url ( "/") , all url return an nginx 404 page. The app runs on venv and I have no idea on how to configure nginx so that they can be served.

I don't know whether to update nginx.conf, default site or something else.

I tried looking for nginx configuration for flask but found no appropriate resource.

The app looks like this

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return "Test"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I excpect /test to open, same way it opens on development server, but returns 404 on nginx.

Comment: What does your current nginx config look like for that site?

Comment: If you want a working example to crib from, https://github.com/davewsmith/nginx-uwsgi-flask-starter has an nginx config in the `config` folder.